# Проблема миграции проекта с xcode 7 на xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Появилась острая необходимость миграции проекта с xcode 7 на xcode 6. Проект достаточно большой.
При попытке запуска получаю ошибку линкера (+очень огромный лог перед ошибкой):
`312 dublicate symbols for architecture x86_64`. 
В xcode 7 все запускается прекрасно. Неужели это банальная несовместимость выходит таким боком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дубликатные символы появляются, когда какие-то функции/методы определены более одного раза. И вряд ли здесь дело в несовместимости кода. Исходя из Вашей ситуации, можно предположить несколько причин:

1. Возможно, у Вас стоит флаг `-ObjC` в *Other Linker Flags*, который заставляет сваливать все объектные файлы в одну кучу, что приводит к дубликатам функций:

   > This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.
2. Возможно, какие-то файлы были скопированы в проект более одного раза.
3. Возможно, где-то импортируется .m-файл, хотя маловероятно, если код без изменений.

Думаю, в такой ситуации лучше добавлять код в проект частями, чтобы сразу находить причины проблем, когда они появляются.

Comment: Смысл в том, что он ругается на библиотеку PayPalMobile (А именно на файлы с расширением *.a). При удалении этой библиотеки (проект далее в ней не нуждается) выплывает ошибка линкера с сообщением о невозможности найти эту библиотеку, однако где нужно удалить сам линк на нее - я пока не понял. Хотя это уже совсем другой вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Очисть проект: Product -> Clean

Comment: возможно в проекте есть какой нибудь файлик с названием "Constant.h" где есть не статические переменные